# jQuery Custom events for data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a custom widget system for an app I'm working on. What I want to have happen is the ability for one widget to update another widget by changing out the data attributes value. On page load, the initial data is loaded into this `data-attr` via PHP and using jQuery to switch out the data after the fact.

For instance, one widget would work as follows:

- PHP loads json data into DOM element
- jQuery function is passed the elements ID and retrieves data from `data-attr` and uses it to produce a graph for example
- Based on user interaction, another widget sends data to element's `data-attr` while also firing a custom jQuery event
- Initial function gets the new data and updates it's graph

I've started a demo:

```js
// Ranomize Number & Replace Variable
$(function() {
  $('#random').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    num = Math.random() + 100;
    $('#data').attr('data-receiver', num);
  });
});

// Receive Data & Output
$(function() {
  var output = $('#output');
  var received = $('#data').attr('data-receiver');
  output.html(received);

  // Not sure what to do next
});
```

```css
#content {
  background: #efefef;
  margin: 40px auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="data" data-receiver="10"></div>
  <strong>Output:</strong>
  <span id="output"></span>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a href="#" id="random">Randomize</a>
</div>
```

But to be honest I'm not sure how to start. I have some code putting a random value into the receiving DOM element, but not sure how to setup the event or write another function to receive and update the `#output` div.

I'm happy to answer questions or write more code to help better explain my goal. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to do a custom event you can do $(selector).on('whatever', callbackFunction);  Then it can be executed with $(selector).trigger('whatever');

Comment: So if hypothetically I have two functions: `sender()` and `receiver()` to send and receive data from the DOM element, which one do I place as the `callbackFunction`?

Comment: Do you want both of these elements to talk together with sender() and receiver()?

Comment: Sorry both elements? The idea is that data flows like this `sender_func( trigger event ) -> DOM element data-attr -> receiver_func( gets data when trigger occurs )`. So there is one element in the middle. The idea is that I will build a view, the function on the receiver side will get data on load, IF it's data ever gets updated, it then gets the new data and does what it needs. If it doesn't ever get data, then it never changes.

Comment: Something like this maybe?  http://jsfiddle.net/6s65myhr/

Comment: Not quite, but it's given me a little bit more understanding. It's the understanding hurdle I just need to get over. Ps. I've learned that the using `.data('attr')` function in jQuery doesn't work for updating the DOM, it only gets to get a value on load and not after. Should use `.attr('data-attr')` in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77562/discussion-between-taplar-and-dvoutt).

Comment: Please always add code example in the question. JsFiddle may be down one day. Also jsFiddle is not required as StackOverflows provides built in code snipplets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing `.queue()` , `.promise()` to create a "subscriber" , "publisher" pattern

```
var output = $("#output");

var process = function process(next) {
    // `this`:`#data`
    var num = Math.random() * 100;
    $(this).data("receiver", num);
    return next()
};

var update = function update() {
  // `this`:`#data`
  $(this).promise("process").then(function(received) {
    // `received`:`#data`,
    // do stuff with `received`
    console.log(received.data("receiver"));
    output.html(received.data("receiver"));
    received.queue("process", process);
    // add `process` to `received` `"process"` queue
    console.log(received, received.queue("process"));
  });
};

// queue first call to `process`
$("#data").queue("process", process);

$("#random").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    update.call($("#data").dequeue("process"));       
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jev4wuej/2/

Comment: What's the benefit of the subscriber / publisher pattern versus the method I was outlining (for my growth of knowledge).

Comment: @dvoutt Not certain about exact meaning of _"benefit"_ ? Depends on how "benefit" defined ? Separating portions , "layers" , or "steps" into distinct blocks performing distinct parts of a "process" ? Ability to add catch error , add error callbacks; other processes to each "part" block ?  _"What I want to have happen is the ability for one widget to update another widget by changing out the data attributes value."_ See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/#pubsub

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use custom events which allows for the code to be more decoupe and independent of each other.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jev4wuej/3/)

### JS

```
var toolbar = {
    init: function() {
        $('.data-randomizer').click(this.handleRandomizer);
    },
    handleRandomizer: function() {
        var number = Math.random() + 100;
        $.event.trigger('update-request.storage-widget', [number]);
    }
};
var output = {
    init: function() {
        $(document).on('updated.storage-widget', this.handleDisplay);
        $.event.trigger('data-request.storage-widget', this.handleDisplay);
    },
    handleDisplay: function(event, number) {
        $('.data-output-widget #output').text(number);
    },
    requestOut: function() {

    }
};
var storage = {
    init: function() {
        $(document).on('update-request.storage-widget', this.handleUpdateRequest);
        $(document).on('data-request.storage-widget', this.handleDataRequest);
    },
    handleUpdateRequest: function(event, number) {
        $('.data-storage-widget').attr('data-receiver', number);
        $.event.trigger('updated.storage-widget', [number]);
    },
    handleDataRequest: function(event, callback) {
        var number = $('.data-storage-widget').data('receiver');
        callback(event, number);
    }
};

toolbar.init();
storage.init();
output.init();
```

### HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="data-storage-widget" data-receiver="10"></div>
    <div class="data-output-widget">
        <strong>Output:</strong>
        <span id="output"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="tool-bar-widget">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="data-randomizer">Randomize</a>
    </div>

</div>
```